# I could not have not noticed

Tags: phrases, double-negation

"As a geek I could not have not noticed the error in your calculation."

This is how I would say this in Slovak language, is this correct in English? If not, what could I use instead?

**EDIT:** The expected meaning should be: Because I am a geek the error in your calculation was immediately apparent to me (even without focusing on it).

Comment: What is it supposed to mean?  Does it  mean you *are* a geek  and weren't able to notice something? Does it mean that you *aren't* a geek but even if you *had* been a geek you wouldn't have noticed?   Please explain how this sentence would be used. Can you give a scenario?

Comment: Please see the edit, I did not realise it may not be clear to everyone.

Comment: Look everyone, it's a correct use of a double negative!  I did not fail to not notice.

Comment: Well, I read straight past the double-negative without seeing it. That is because it isn't idiomatic in its present form. I see the intention though. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

> As a geek, I couldn't help but notice the error in your calculation.

Captures the notion of noticing an error without specifically looking for one. It also has a very "soft" impression, because you (presumably) don't want to sound like you're criticizing when you announce such a correction.

Answer (score 2):

Better would be

> I would not have failed to notice . . .

or, still better,

> I would not have overlooked . . .

Answer (score 2):

One possible alternative would be:

> As a geek I could not fail to notice the error in your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

> "As a geek I could not have not noticed the error in your calculation."

When I read this I completely missed the second 'not'. The reason is that it wouldn't be said in precisely that way. I suggest:

> [Speaking] as a geek, I couldn't *not* notice the error in your calculation.

It is important to emphasise the 'not' because it would be strongly emphasised in speech.

You could also stick closer to your original with a slight change in the word order but it would be less likely and less idiomatic:

> As a geek, I couldn't *not* have noticed the error in your calculation.

I'd point out the new positioning of the 'not'.

Comment: I disagree that it wouldn't be said in that way.  It's awkward, casual, perhaps colloquial, but I wouldn't be entirely surprised to hear it.  Someone I know was once told, when asking whether it would be possible to skip one leg of a multiple-leg air ticket, "you cannot not fly."

Comment: @phoog - Did you actually read my answer? I didn't say a double-negative is incorrect. I simply said the OP's version isn't quite right and  gave an example of a more idiomatic version.

Comment: Yes I did, and I've re-read it, and I stick by my comment.

Comment: In that case, what point are you making with your example, "You cannot not fly"?  That is perfectly normal and I wouldn't criticise it in the least.

Comment: It seems equal to "could not have not noticed" except for the fact that the tense is different.

Comment: The difference is that in your example and in both of mine, the two *not*s are next to each other. In the OP's example the second *not* is placed between 'have' and 'noticed'. That placement is what caused me (and presumably Nonnal)  to misread it and it's also unidiomatic in my opinion.

Comment: Aha, I see.  Surely "couldn't not have noticed" is more traditional, but the issue is similar to that of the split infinitive, where "to not x" is gaining popularity at the expense of "not to x." That is, *not* is increasingly seen as being more strongly associated with the main verb than *to* is, and the same seems to be true of *not* and the auxiliary verb.  At least this is happening in the US; I can't tell to what degree it is also happening in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct in informal speech, at least, and fairly idiomatic. But you *must* put emphasis on the second "not" --

"I could not have **not** noticed ..."

And, of course, in written form the "not" will likely lost to the reader if not bolded (though this reader noticed it the very first time through).